# Does core Django supports migration without django-south or similar app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration, django-south

Does Django consists of a migration concept without south app?

If not why didn't they include it in Django 1.4? (Since, it's a must have).

Comment: You might as well ask, why it hasn't been included in earlier versions. Django-south has been around for quite some time. Also, why is it a must-have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't. South is considered as the 'de facto' standard for database migration in Django. [Further reading](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SchemaEvolution) can be found in the Django development wiki.

From the version 1.2 release notes:

> Contrib-01 (Add South to contrib) - general consensus - including that
> of South's lead developer - is that South isn't yet ready to be a
> bonafide part of Django.

This, most probably, is still valid. South has its limitations, it still has gaps that could be considered as flaws when being a django.contrib module.

That said, I want to add: south still is extremely useful.

Comment: Why has `south` not being included in contrib.auth if its 'de facto' ?

Answer (score 2):

South is not the only migration app that works with Django. See http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/database-migration/ for some current options. Simon Willison also co-created [Dmigrations](http://code.google.com/p/dmigrations/) but it's old and hasn't had a commit for a few years.

South is generally accepted to be the best at the moment, though I've not tried NashVegas (partly because South is so good, I've not needed to)

Comment: Thanks for the info, but the context of the question was - does core django supports migrations with south or any other similar app.

Answer (score 2):

Following a successful [kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/andrewgodwin/schema-migrations-for-django) campaign, schema migrations will be added to the Django core starting with version 1.7

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#schema-migrations