# Why is django-south not included in django.contrib?

Tags: python, database, django, migration, django-south

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does core django supports migration without django-south or similar app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613932/does-core-django-supports-migration-without-django-south-or-similar-app)

`django-south` is a de facto standard for db migrations in django, moreover django itself doesn't supports db-migrations.

Now, since django carries some high-quality apps that are almost must haves in `django.contrib` then :

- Why doesn't it include django-south ?
- What is the thought processes behind that ?
- Is it not good enough or licencing issues ?

### Related Question :

- [Does core django supports migration without django-south or similar app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613932/does-django-supports-migration-without-django-south)

Comment: django-staticfiles just made it's way into django.contrib, maybe south will come one day.

Comment: django-south has been there for long, and we just saw the release of django 1.4 - It was an obvious choice to include if they wanted it in. But something kept it from being included - What was that ?

Comment: You have already accepted an answer in your previous question that is almost identical to this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613932/does-django-supports-migration-with-django-south). Why open this question?

Comment: I'd say the biggest reason is release schedules, django which is a widely known and used framework can't produce releases and new updates as often as a smaller package would. Would it benefit django-south not being able to release a new update with added functionality every few month instead of providing a stack of new functionality every django release unless you run the "nightly" build?

Comment: @möter It is a different question all together !

Comment: Adding it to related questions.. !

Comment: Dear downvoter, wherever you are, please add a reason before downvoting.. That'd be nice..

Comment: @DanielX: At least *now*, I don't think it would matter much. South has matured enough that releases are now few and far between. In fact I think Django has released 1.3 and 1.4 without South seeing a single release.

Comment: The other question (duplicate from) is poorly answered (maybe because the only ones who can answer correctly are django main contributors who are not spending time on SO), thus I consider this one as legitimate since it's better formulated and the question poster is putting efforts to have a decent answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I remember watching a video where Jacob Kaplan-Moss answered this very question. Whilst I can't remember the talk word for word, his response was on the lines of - They didn't want to bundle South into Django, as South was still in its infant stages and by integrating South at this stage would potentially slow down its development.

Update 03/13 - Andrew Godwin of South fame has [kickstarted](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/andrewgodwin/schema-migrations-for-django) a project to get database migrations built into the core of Django. Expect this to land in Django 1.6 / 1.7.

Update 04/14 - Migration made it into the core of Django 1.7. You can read more about migrations @ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. People under-estimates questions on stack-overflow.

Comment: Can't post an answer so: Django 1.7 (currently the development version) includes migrations - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/